# Is there any way that I could customize HTTP response status?

Tags: http, go, web

I need to customize the HTTP Status in a handler in my Web Server, but I found that golang doesn't seem to support completely custom HTTP Response..
For example:

```golang
w.WriteHeader(999)
```

here is the `curl` result:

```
$ curl -vk -i localhost:9898/hello

*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 9898 (#0)
> GET /hello HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9898
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 999 status code 999
HTTP/1.1 999 status code 999
< Date: Wed, 19 Jun 2019 02:01:09 GMT
Date: Wed, 19 Jun 2019 02:01:09 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
Content-Length: 0
```

the `status code` in the result seems couldn't be modified.. but, I want to define my own status, like `Bad Request: xxx`.

Is there any good ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Keep in mind that machines aren't meant to use the status text, only the nuemric code. The text is intended for humans. A program that attempts to do something with the text is violating the RFC.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't think you understand what I really need and want..The status text is for humans, of course. But there are always some weird requirements, aren't there? Anyway, thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think what you're trying is currently supported.

As per [the official documentation of `net/http.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter):

> The provided code must be a valid HTTP 1xx-5xx status code. Only one header may be written. Go does not currently support sending user-defined 1xx informational headers, with the exception of 100-continue response header that the Server sends automatically when the Request.Body is read.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question. You've talked about the accepted status code values, but not the descriptive text for them.

Answer (score 4):

This functionality is handled in [net/http/server.go](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L1482):

```
func writeStatusLine(bw *bufio.Writer, is11 bool, code int, scratch []byte) {
    if is11 {
        bw.WriteString("HTTP/1.1 ")
    } else {
        bw.WriteString("HTTP/1.0 ")
    }
    if text, ok := statusText[code]; ok {
        bw.Write(strconv.AppendInt(scratch[:0], int64(code), 10))
        bw.WriteByte(' ')
        bw.WriteString(text)
        bw.WriteString("\r\n")
    } else {
        // don't worry about performance
        fmt.Fprintf(bw, "%03d status code %d\r\n", code, code)
    }
}
```

From this you can see that the descriptive text comes from the standard library's internal list of status codes, the same exposed by the [StatusText](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StatusText) function.

If there is no known text, the place-holder "status code" is used, with no option to change this behavior.

So with the standard library `http` package, there is no way to do what you desire.  Your options are to fork and/or re-implement this functionality in your own package, or (possibly a long-shot), submit a feature request upstream to change this functionality.

If this functionality is really necessary for some reason, one last-ditch, desperate approach might be to write some sort of proxy, that intercepts the HTTP output, and transforms the 'status code' text for you. You might be able to do this by writing your own implementation/wrapper of [`net.Listener`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Listener), which you then pass to `http.Serve`. This won't be very efficient, and is highly discouraged, unless you have absolutely no other option.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer inspired me a lot !